# How to implement a socket server?

Tags: sockets, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I am trying to implement a socket server in my supervision tree. I have added the following to the main supervisor:

```
supervisor(AcceptorSup, [Application.get_env(:appname, :port)])
supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: ClientSupervisor]])
```

And here is the `AcceptorSup` module

```
defmodule AcceptorSup do
  use Supervisor
  require Logger

  def start_link(port) do
    Supervisor.start_link __MODULE__, [port: port], name: __MODULE__
  end

  def init(args \\ []) do
    port = Keyword.get args, :port, 8000
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen port, active: false, reuseaddr: true, packet: :raw
    Logger.info "Server started on port #{port}"

    children = [
      worker(Acceptor, [socket], function: :start)
    ]

    num_childs = Application.get_env :appname, :acceptors_num, 50
    for _ <- 1..num_childs do
      Task.start fn ->
        Supervisor.start_child AcceptorSup, []
      end
    end

    supervise(children, strategy: :simple_one_for_one, max_restarts: 1000, max_seconds: 10)
  end
end
```

And here is the basic code of `Acceptor`

```
defmodule Acceptor do
  require Logger

  def start(socket) when is_port(socket) do
    Task.start_link fn -> serve_client(socket) end
  end

  defp serve_client(socket) when is_port(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept socket
    Logger.info "A client connected #{address client}"
    {:ok, pid} = Task.Supervisor.start_child ClientSupervisor, fn -> serve(client) end
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process client, pid
    Supervisor.start_child AcceptorSup, []
  end
end
```

So, I start a `Task.Supervisor` to handle clients, and that works fine. I also start a supervisor, of type `simple_one_for_one` to handle listeners. Each child, waits for a connection, and when given, spawns a task for client in the task supervisor and starts another child instead of itself. The problem is that if the rate of clients connecting and disconnecting is high enough, the supervisor would crash, because it would reach values of `max_restarts` and `max_seconds`. I can increase the threshold by increasing values, but it just doesn't seem right to me. I am searching for a way to handle clients' connection and disconnection, and not hitting these limits.

How should one implement this, while also respecting the supervision tree? I don't want to use a custom process management, because I'm almost sure there is something I'm missing here. Anyway, Erlang/OTP was designed to handle such problems, right?

Comment: I think [ranch](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch) may be a good project to both use and learn from.

Comment: The listener supervisor uses `simple_one_for_one` strategy, it will not die due to `max_restarts` condition since it will never restart any process. For other strategies, don't forget that if you end a process with the reason `normal`, it is not restarted either.